# Microarray Meta-Analysis and Cross-Platform

Tags: r

I have a microarray dataset with Agilent platform, all of the samples are cancerous, I need normal or control samples to compare with cancerous samples, can I combine control samples from another platform (for example Illumina) to Agilent platform? and then remove the batch effect.

I would be grateful if you could guide me to do it.

Comment: The technologies are extremely different, there is no way a correct statistical analysis (with limma, edgeR or DESeq2) would give you anything meaningful. Even two experiments with the exact same technology done on different days tend to have significant batch effects. And to correct batch effect, you would need a better design (not all cancer on one day and control on other, or you have no way to know what changes are due to condition and what changes are due to batch effect).

Comment: Also, this kind of question might find more answers on [the bioinfo stack exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming in R. It is more related to analysis of a specific type of data. Might be more suited for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable guidance, I will check the Bioinformatics Stack Exchange website.